# ElasticSearch aggregation add extra field as array to buckets

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, aggregate

I'm pretty new in aggregation with elastic search.

I'm looking for a way to add custom field to every bucket of the aggregation, this field should be an array or string with some separator between every particular item.

I have elastic search mappings mappings

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "place": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have an aggregate query

```
  {
  size: 0,
  query: {...},
  aggs: {
    "merchants": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "order": {
          "max_score": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_score": {
          "max": {
            "script": "_score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I having the result like that:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 82,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "merchants": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "Post Office",
                    "doc_count": 82,
                    "max_score": {
                        "value": 1.7627471685409546
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In the example this result contains 82 docs.
My goal is that every bucket has an extra field which contains every document _id, better as array for example "refs": [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to add another `terms` sub-aggregation on the `_id` field:

```
{
  size: 0,
  query: {...},
  aggs: {
    "merchants": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "order": {
          "max_score": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ids": {               <--- add this
          "terms": {
            "field": "_id",
            "size": 100
          }
        },
        "max_score": {
          "max": {
            "script": "_score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I somehow omit "size": 100? Because I don't know the exact value, which should be there

Comment: You can set an arbitrarily high value, but by default only 10 terms will be returned.